# iOS must run pod install after every checkup

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, dependency-management

I am using cocoapods for an iOS project and every time I checkout a new branch I have to run `pod install`, as the pods don't run.

Is there a solution to not have to run `pod install` every time?

Comment: I am pretty confused about down voting or about considering it a primarily opinion based question. He does not ask if it is a good a idea or not (opinion based). He asks about how do it (it is not primary opinion-based).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First make sure that `Podfile`, `Podfile.lock` are not ignored, and in the `git` directory.

I guess when you switch branches, the `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` of the two branches are inconsistent, so you will need to re-`Pod install`.

The pods folder is relatively large and does not need to be uploaded, so it can be ignored first, but `Podfile`, `Podfile.lock` cannot be ignored, `!` means not ignored.

Maybe you can try setting `gitignore`

Like this

```
# CocoaPods

Pods

!Podfile

!Podfile.lock
```

Comment: according to https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html PodFile.lock should not be ignored

Comment: You may not use `gitignore`，`!`Indicates not to ignore

Comment: yep, sorry, my miss

Answer (score 1):

You can add and commit (adding Pods folder) all the installed pod libraries inside your own source code repository. In this way they will be restored during the checkout.

So you have to run pod only for updating the libraries or the pod install command only when you have to add a new one.

Take a look to the [Cocoapods documentation](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control) about the pros/cons of this practice.

> Benefits of checking in the Pods directory: After cloning the repo, the project can immediately build and run, even without having CocoaPods installed on the machine. **There is no need to run pod install**, and no Internet connection is necessary.The Pod artifacts (code/libraries) are always available, even if the source of a Pod (e.g. GitHub) were to go down. The Pod artifacts are guaranteed to be identical to those in the original installation after cloning the repo.

If you are using git then you have to edit the .gitignore file in order allow the adding of the Pods directory

Comment: what do you mean by check-in?

Comment: I mean add Pods folder and all sub-folders  containing all the libraries source code to your own source code repository.

Comment: Which kind of source code repo are you using it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't **commit** your **master** branch with **pods** or there is a **.gitignore** file ignores **pods**